# FlashDevelop - Classes not displayed in the inteliisense even after pressing ctl+space

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

Straight question first

How to make Flash Develop to recognize all classes inside my project and from my swcs in library

Long way story

I have migrated from Flash Builder to Flash Develop. I really like FD because of its simplicity.

The only one thing is really frustrating to me is it doesn't list classes in the inteliisense. It basically doesn't recognize all classes which are present in my own project. Example I have UtilsCommon class in utils package which is in the root folder (src). Now, usually the intellisense starts listing the classes matching with the beginning letters of the class name. But it doesn't recognize the class even after I type the entire class name and the worse case it doesn't recognize even when I press ctrl+space.

In that case what I need to do is to type the fully qualified name of the class like in this case utils.UtilsCommon then it recognizes the class and it removed the package name and imports the package/class and highlights the code.

I initially thought it has problem with my project files and once I add it using fully qualified name it adds to the list. But soon I found out that it remembers it only in that class and I have to type fully qualified class name in different class again. **And worse I fund today is that it just doesnt even recognize the core classes and global functions like MovieClip and getTimer()**

I don't know if this is the un changable expected behaviour. Let me know if I can do some tweeks to make FD smarter.

Answer (score 1):

FlashDevelop behaves differently than Flash Builder and doesn't show everything by default.

However Ctrl+Alt+Space should display all the possible classes and tool functions. Selecting a class in this list will generate the appropriate 'import'.